# Graph API doesnt return Profile's picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), and it says that for retrieve picture I need to use an access token. So, I've use it using `publish_actions` and `email` as scopre/permission, but I don't see any `picture" returned on the JSON:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/myNickname/?access_token=myAccessToken
```

the rest of data is returned, the ones where access_token is required not. I should use User Access Token, not App Access Token.

The same happens for the others field, such as `age_range`. It is not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the doc for `age_range` that the field will be retrieved only if you specify it in your request:

> The user's age range; only returned if specifically requested via the fields URL parameter

The same happens to `picture` property. The problem is, that they didn't mention it in the documentation.

To get `picture`, specify in your request:

```
/me?fields=picture
```

Comment: But this is another link! I can't get them all (user data+picture) with a single request?

Comment: @markzzz To get all user data with the special field you can do only by specifying the fields you need. For example like this one: `/me?fields=id,first_name,gender,picture,age_range`. here I ask for 5 fields and you can ask for more in the single request.

Comment: @markzzz The documentation isn't good not just here :). I already opened a few bugs that relate to bad documentation. And I just opened another bug for this, picture, issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/145463422330536

Comment: @markzzz Facebook resolved the bug and updated the documentation for `picture` property: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/